# change in style of material ui InputLabel component not working. code below

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the color of the label which is showing in grey color? Depending on the theme of the page I have to change the color of the label or even if I remove the override color it should work.

Example remove the default one:

```
.MuiFormLabel-root { 
    /* color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54); //default in the browser
}
```

```
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      root: {
        "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
          color: "white"
        }
      }
    }));
    export default function SelectBox(props) {
        const classes = useStyles();
        return (
             <FormControl
                style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <InputLabel shrink className={classes.root}>
                    {props.label}
                </InputLabel> 
    </FormControl>
        )
    }
```

Comment: "&.MuiFormLabel-root" just remove space.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `classes` object and overirde the `root` which corresponds to `.MuiInputLabel-root`

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { FormControl } from "@material-ui/core";
import { InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: "red"
  }
}));

export default function SelectBox(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <FormControl style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <InputLabel shrink classes={{ root: classes.root }}>
        {props.label}
      </InputLabel>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

To have result like this -

[image]

Working sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/update-input-label-color-kzew2?file=/demo.js:0-513